# Registring line as a custom geometry in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I'm following [Register a Custom Geometry](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/components/geometry.html#register-a-custom-geometry) example to register line. It generates an error in THREE.js. Here is the trace of the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Mt.fromGeometry (three.js:12300)
    at St.fromGeometry (three.js:14186)
    at toBufferGeometry (geometry.js:134)
    at createGeometry (geometry.js:106)
    at r.getOrCreateGeometry (geometry.js:48)
    at i.update (geometry.js:41)
    at i.updateProperties (component.js:212)
    at i.module.exports.Component (component.js:37)
    at new i (component.js:330)
    at HTMLElement.value (a-entity.js:366)
```

This is the HTML that should recreate the error:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./a-line.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene>
        <a-entity geometry="primitive:line"></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

and this is a-line.js:

```
AFRAME.registerGeometry('line', {
    schema: {
       start: {default: '0 0 -5'},
       end: { default: '0 10 -5'}
    },
    init: function (data) {

    var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0077ff }); 
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var inputPts = [data.start, data.end];
    geometry.vertices.push.call(
      geometry.vertices,
      inputPts.map(function (vertex) {
          var points = vertex.split(' ').map(parseFloat);
          return new THREE.Vector3(points[0], points[1], points[2]);
      })
    );

   this.geometry = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It was a mistake. Changed it to`aframe`.

Comment: In case someone else needs to draw lines I ended up using [meshLine component for A-Frame](https://github.com/andreasplesch/aframe-meshline-component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a line is a Mesh, not a geometry, that consists of both a geometry and a material, the correct way would be to create a `line` component, not a `line` geometry.

```
AFRAME.registerGeometry('line', {
schema: {
   start: {default: '0 0 -5'},
   end: { default: '0 10 -5'}
},
init: function () {
var data = this.data

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0077ff }); 
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var inputPts = [data.start, data.end];
geometry.vertices.push.call(
  geometry.vertices,
  inputPts.map(function (vertex) {
      var points = vertex.split(' ').map(parseFloat);
      return new THREE.Vector3(points[0], points[1], points[2]);
  })
);

this.el.setObject3D('mesh', new THREE.Line( geometry, material ));
}
});
```